# I want to find a result from a maths exam where to find a result you have get to achieve minimum scores

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a program that calculates a result based on certain criteria where what score you get (Between 1-5) for 6 questions, 2 C standard, 2 B standard and 2 A standard, is your result. Here is the criteria: [image: Link to image]

So far the best thing I can come up with is a massive if statement with each possibility (I've only done it for a part of achieving an A):

```
function KP() {
  var C1 = document.getElementById("kpC1").value;
  var B1 = document.getElementById("kpB1").value;
  var A1 = document.getElementById("kpA1").value;
  var C2 = document.getElementById("kpC2").value;
  var B2 = document.getElementById("kpB2").value;
  var A2 = document.getElementById("kpA2").value;

  var result;

  if (C1 >= 4 && B1 >= 4 && A1 >= 4 && C2 >= 4 && B2 >= 4 && A2 >= 4) {
    var result = "A";
  } else if (C1 == 5 && B1 >= 4 && A1 >= 3 && C2 == 5 && B2 >= 4 && A2 >= 4) {
    var result = "A";
  } else if (C1 == 5 && B1 >= 4 && A1 >= 4 && C2 == 5 && B2 >= 4 && A2 >= 3) {
    var result = "A";
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much more elegant to count up the number of scores that equal or exceed each number, and the number of scores that equal or are less than each number. For example:

```
function KP() {
  var C1 = document.getElementById("kpC1").value;
  var B1 = document.getElementById("kpB1").value;
  var A1 = document.getElementById("kpA1").value;
  var C2 = document.getElementById("kpC2").value;
  var B2 = document.getElementById("kpB2").value;
  var A2 = document.getElementById("kpA2").value;

  const scores = [C1, B1, A1, C2, B2, A2];
  const numScoresHigherThan = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => i + 1) // 1 to 5
    .reduce((a, testScore) => {
      a[testScore] = scores.reduce((count, num) => count + (num >= testScore), 0);
      return a;
    }, {});
  const numScoresLessThan = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => i + 1) // 1 to 5
    .reduce((a, testScore) => {
      a[testScore] = scores.reduce((count, num) => count + (num <= testScore), 0)
      return a;
    }, {});


  let result;
  if (
    numScoresHigherThan[4] === 6
    || (numScoresHigherThan[3] === 6 && numScoresLessThan[3] === 1)
  ) result = 'A';
  // ...
}
```

Live example for As and Bs:

```js
function grade(scores) {
  const numScoresHigherThan = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => i + 1) // 1 to 5
  .reduce((a, testScore) => {
    a[testScore] = scores.reduce((count, num) => count + (num >= testScore), 0);
    return a;
  }, {});
  const numScoresLessThan = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => i + 1) // 1 to 5
  .reduce((a, testScore) => {
    a[testScore] = scores.reduce((count, num) => count + (num <= testScore), 0)
    return a;
  }, {});
  
  
  let result;
  if (
    numScoresHigherThan[4] === 6
    || (numScoresHigherThan[3] === 6 && numScoresLessThan[3] === 1)
  ) result = 'A';
  else if (
    numScoresHigherThan[4] >= 3 && numScoresLessThan[3] <= 1
  ) result = 'B';
  else result = 'worse';
  console.log(result);
}

grade([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]);
grade([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]);
grade([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3]);
grade([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer: you should definitely put all your values (`C1`, etc.) in an array.

Some cases are pretty easy, let's take the score `E` for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < scoresArray.length; i++) {
    if (scoresArray[i] <= 2) {
        var result = "E";
    }
}
```

I'm sure you can find other shortcuts that would make assigning the other scores more concise!

Note: I assumed that the criteria for assigning a `E` is *"There is at least one question that has a score of 2 or less"*.

Comment: it does not help for mixed conditions.